# A regular n,2d graph is a good expander.

Tags: computational-complexity

> ### Context
>
> Reading about Expanders
>
> ### Setup
>
> A regular n,2d graph is generated as follows:
>     generate d random permutations of [n]
>     connect the edges; giving a n,2d regular graph
>
> ### Question
>
> How do I prove that this graph is a good expander?
>
> ### Known:
>
> Broder/Shamir has a paper "On the second eigenvalue of random regular graphs." that proves this statement. However, it uses martingales, which I do not understand.
>
> ### Also Known:
>
> Many texts provide a short proof for bipartite graphs; but not the general case.
>
> ### Request
>
> Is there an elementary (combinatorial) proof of the general case? [For the graphs generated above.]

Thanks!

Comment: There are several related but different definitions of an expander (the most popular ones are in terms of the spectral gap, vertex expansion, or edge expansion). Which one are you using?

Comment: It's worth learning about martingales (in addition to looking for another proof), actually, since they are an extremely useful tool.  The beginning of Chapter 7 in Alon and Spencer's book on the probabilistic method gives a nice introduction, and in a couple of pages it covers everything I think you need for the Broder and Shamir proof.

Comment: Maybe it's time to learn about martingales...

Answer (score 5):

This is can be done by a counting argument -- if the graph is not a a good expander then there is a subset with a small boundary. Given any such subset there are relatively a few permutations which preserve it, and summing over all possible subsets one sees that only
a few $d$ tuples of permutations give graphs which are not good expanders.

This breaks if $d$ is very small or your notion of a good expander is very strong.
This argument can be found in Lubotzky's book.

Comment: @kassabov: "Lubotzky's book" is not very specific...

Comment: Igor: Lubotzky has only one book on expanders --  "Descrete Groups, Expanding graphs and invariant measures" Progress in mathematics 125 Birkhauser 1994